ASP.NET MVC .NET 8.0 prevent route from handling image requests
I have a .Net 8.0 MVC project and in my Program.cs file I have the following route set up:
app.MapControllerRoute(
  name: "ArticlePage",
  pattern: "/{landingSlug}/{articleSlug}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Article", action = "Index" });

The problem is that this controller is hit whenever an image is requested e.g. "/images/something.jpg". How can I configure the route to ignore requests for images?

What is the significance intended for "{landingSlug}" etc? That route pattern looks very problematic. You're basically telling MVC to expect any and all 2-part route, and always go to /Article/Index.

@StevePy good point! I'm serving content from a CMS and was planning for {landingSlug} to be like the root/category page and then {articleSlug} to be the article page. I guess I can hard-code that root path instead as I have only a handful of items relating to {landingSlug}.
Feel free to add that comment (or similar) as an answer and I will accept.
